# Get notified on file changes in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-documents

I create a file with name `File - 1.jpg` on two different devices and put it in iCloud container.

I don't use `UIDocument` and even though I tried to use it, it does not create a conflict. Instead what I see is that documents are being automatically renamed and moved by iCloud.

So after upload one file or another becomes `File - 2.jpg`. All of this is fine but now I don't have a reference to file so I have no idea which is which...

Is there any way to get notified on the app side that file was renamed/moved/deleted in iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I had to create a class that implements `NSFilePresenter` and point it to iCloud container folder.

Live updates from iCloud may be quite late and happen only when iCloud pulls metadata.

Also, I had to associate each created file with each device and iCloud account and persist this data, in my case in CoreData. This is where `ubiquityIdentityToken` becomes useful.

All file ops in iCloud container should certainly happen using `NSFileCoordinator`.

For add/remove events it's better to use `NSMetadataQuery`, `NSFileCoordinator` does not report those at all, but is still useful to detect when files were moved, this is what metadata query reports as updates.

This is a very basic boilerplate that can be used as a starting point:

```
@interface iCloudFileCoordinator () <NSFilePresenter>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *containerID;
@property (nonatomic) NSURL *containerURL;

@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

@end

@implementation iCloudFileCoordinator

- (instancetype)initWithContainerID:(NSString *)containerID {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.containerID = containerID;
    self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.operationQueue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceBackground;

    [self addFilePresenter];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeFilePresenter];
}

- (void)addFilePresenter {
    [NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:self];
}

- (void)removeFilePresenter {
    [NSFileCoordinator removeFilePresenter:self];
}

#pragma mark - NSFilePresenter
#pragma mark - 

- (NSURL *)presentedItemURL {
    NSURL *containerURL = self.containerURL;

    if(containerURL) {
        return containerURL;
    }

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    containerURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:self.containerID];

    self.containerURL = containerURL;

    return containerURL;
}

- (NSOperationQueue *)presentedItemOperationQueue {
    return self.operationQueue;
}

- (void)presentedSubitemAtURL:(NSURL *)oldURL didMoveToURL:(NSURL *)newURL {
    NSLog(@"Moved file from %@ to %@", oldURL, newURL);
}

/*
 ... and other bunch of methods that report on sub item changes ...
 */

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CKSubscription**:

Upon initialization of  CKSubscription you can specify the notification options:

- CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecord*Creation*
- CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecord*Deletion*
- CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecord*Update*
- CKSubscriptionOptionsFires*Once*

[iCloud Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW1)

These looked useful for you too:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/cloudkit-the-fastest-route-to-implementing-the-auto-synchronizing-app-youve-been-working-on/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial

Comment: If I got it right, this is for CloudKit and not for iCloud Documents. I believe those are two separate things. CloudKit uses `CKAsset` and `CKRecord` to store files, while I iCloud documents is purely a magic folder on disk.

Comment: Ahh my bad im sorry I didn't realize that was the context, i figured CloudKit was for developers to leverage iCloud

Comment: I didn't work much with CKAssets so I had no idea they are so similar. I've added icloud-documents tag to my question to avoid the frustration. (this is how it's referenced in Xcode)